# Database connectivity in android 2.3.3

Tags: android, database, logging

I am making an android app on 2.3.3 version,but while connecting my app to database it is giving following error,
 database code is as follows,plz look through it and suggest a best change.

```
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------// 
class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
 {
  private static String DB_NAME ="Akhbarwala.sqlite";// Database name 
  private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window 
  private static String DB_PATH = "/sdcard/"; 
   private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;  
  private final Context mContext;


   DataBaseHelper(final Context context)
   {
  super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
  + File.separator +
   DB_NAME, null, 1);
   this.mContext = context; 
    }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
 public void createDataBase() throws IOException 
 { 
   boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
  if(!mDataBaseExist) 
   {    
 Log.e("Error in Finding Database", "Please Insert the Database in SD Card");
    } 
  } 
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
  private boolean checkDataBase() 
   { 
     File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH+DB_NAME); 
    return dbFile.exists(); 
} 
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------// 
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException 
        { 
            InputStream mInput;
        mInput = new FileInputStream(DB_NAME);
        File directory = new File(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
        // String outFileName = DB_PATH;
        if (!directory.exists()) {
       directory.mkdirs();
       }
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory
           .getPath() );
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int mLength; 
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) 
    { 
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
    } 
    mOutput.flush(); 
    mOutput.close(); 
    mInput.close();
} 
          //----------------------------------------------------------------------------// 
        public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
          { 
             String mPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME; 

            this.getWritableDatabase();

        //   mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,                             SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); 
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(mPath, null);

     return mDataBase != null; 

     } 
             //-----------------------------------------------------------------// 
         @Override 
        public synchronized void close()  
        { 
    if(mDataBase != null) 
        mDataBase.close(); 
    super.close(); 
}
         //-------------------------------------------------------------//
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg) {

}
              //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


} 
            //-------------------------------------------------------// 
           }
```

and log file is

```
  10-30 10:05:28.308: D/dalvikvm(10358): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 56K, 51% free                      2682K/5379K, external 383K/517K, paused 117ms
  10-30 10:05:28.658: E/here(10358): SELECT DISTINCT USER_NAME FROM HAWKER_MST WHERE USER_TYPE = 'H' ORDER BY rowid
  10-30 10:05:28.728: I/Database(10358): sqlite returned: error code = 8, msg = prepared statement aborts at 1: [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;]
   10-30 10:05:28.728: E/Database(10358): Failure 8 (attempt to write a readonly database) on 0x91c6f00 when executing 'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;'
    10-30 10:05:28.758: D/AndroidRuntime(10358): Shutting down VM
   10-30 10:05:28.758: W/dalvikvm(10358): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  exception (group=0xb70bc4f0)
   10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
    10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
     10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
     10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteDatabase.java:527)
     10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:481)
     10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:123)
   10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):     at sangi.rawat.akhbaarwala.TestAdapter.getAllLabels(TestAdapter.java:120)
     10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at sangi.rawat.akhbaarwala.Akhbar_main.loadSpinnerData(Akhbar_main.java:93)
      10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):  at sangi.rawat.akhbaarwala.Akhbar_main.onItemSelected(Akhbar_main.java:116)
         10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
      10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):  at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
      10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):  at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
     10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
      10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
         10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):     at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
       10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
       10-30 10:05:28.768: E/AndroidRuntime(10358):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       10-30 10:05:30.648: I/Process(10358): Sending signal. PID: 10358 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your database as writable. Currently you open it as read only and `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;` statement doesn't work